# How to open a file in the same directory as the .jar file of the application?

Tags: java

I'm trying to load a .txt file into an arrayList in java using a combination of relative paths. 
My jar file is in /usr/tool/dist/tool.jar
The file I want to load is in /usr/tool/files/file.txt

I think I was able to retrieve the path of my tool.jar, but how can I go from that path to the one where my file is?

I have the following code

```
// String path should give me '/usr/tool'
File f = new File(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
File dir = f.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile();
String path = dir.toString();
String table1 = this should represent /usr/tool/files/file.txt
BufferedReader buf_table1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(table1)));
```

Comment: If `path` is `"/usr/tool"` as you say (Is it? You should test `System.out.println(path);` and add the results to your question.), why don't you just write something like `table1 = path + "/files/file.txt"`?

Comment: The CLASSPATH is not a file. It is a list of directories and .jar files where .class files can be located. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the path of your `jar` file being executed, `java.class.path` is not the right property. This property may contain more than one file, and you cannot know which is the right one. ([See the docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html))

To find the path of the correct jar file, you can use this instead:

```
URL url = MainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

Where `MainClass` the main class of your tool, or any other class in the same jar file.

Next, the parent `File` of a file is its directory. So the parent `File` of `/usr/tool/dist/tool.jar` is `/usr/tool/dist/`. So if you want to get to `/usr/tool/files/file.txt`, you need to get the parent of the parent, and then from there `files/file.txt`.

Putting it together:

```
File jarFile = new File(MainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
File file = new File(jarFile.getParentFile().getParent(), "files/file.txt");
```

Comment: Yes, replace `MainClass` with the name of your class.